# <img> is larger than its properties

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that is getting extra height somehow and am completely perplexed. Both padding and margin are set to 0. the source image has no extra spacing.  is set to block. Yet, it's still getting an extra 10 pixels or so added to the bottom of the image itself.

This is using bootstrap and the class overrides are listed below.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img src="../assets/WS.png" alt="" class="p-0">
  <p class="m-0">4700/5700 - Switch Selector</P>
</a>

.navbar-brand{
  color: #f0f1f2;
  font-weight: 600;
  >*{
    float: left;
  }
  img{
    display: block;
    width: 75px;
  }
}
```

I would love if anyway has any ideas....

Comment: please provide a working snippet.

Comment: inspect the element with the brower's dev tool, it should show you what's that space if it's part of the image, could it be part of the P tag?

Comment: No, I have confirmed that the extra space is being added directly to the image itself. Not to any parent, child, or sibling element. There is extra height being applied directly to the bottom of the image itself and is causing the parent container to grow as a result.

Comment: @NathanBulkley You need to inspect the element and put in your Question here exactly what's going on, then . ***EDIT*** your question and put a fully working example, else we're simply chasing golden geese...

Comment: Do you have a URL with this in effect, that I can take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies to everyone. After checking the image for the 9th time, I found that there were artifacts of the same color as the background that was causing this perceived extra space.